# Get value from Objects in an Array Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

I am trying to add a voting functionality to a Wordpress website, the available plugins do not meet my requirements.

I have this array wich contains another array with **wp_post objects** (these are users who voted) what I need to do is compare the **current_user_ID** with all the **post_author ids** in the array objects. I need to do this so I can show different content to users who already have voted. Just knowing how to get **post_author value** from the objects in the array and compare it to the **current_user_id** would help out alot. I hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance.

This is how I get the array:

```
<?php $my_post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'supporters', false);
            echo print_r($my_post_meta); ?>
```

And this is the array that shows:

```
 Array ([0] => Array
        (
        [0] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 750
                [post_author] => 46
            )

        [1] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 749
                [post_author] => 47

            )

        [2] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 748
                [post_author] => 1

            )
          ))1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <?php 

    $my_post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'supporters', false);
    $current_user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    foreach( $my_post_meta[0] as $post_object ) {
        if( $post_object->ID == $current_user_ID ) {
            // The current user has voted
        }
    }

   ?>
```